# Custom Xstream/JSON converter for enum

Tags: java, json, enums, xstream, oxm

I have the following `Enum`:

```
public enum MyState {
    Open("opened"),
    Close("closed"),
    Indeterminate("unknown");

    private String desc;

    private MyState(String desc) {
        setDesc(desc);
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return this.desc;
    }

    private void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}
```

I am trying to write an XStream [`Converter`](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html) that will know to map back a JSON element "`mystate`" to a `MyState` instance.

```
"someJson": {
    "object1": {
        "mystate": closed
    }
}
```

This should produce, amongst other objects (`someJson` and `object1`) a `MyState.Close` instance. I've started the `Converter`, but haven't gotten very far:

```
public class MyStateEnumConverter implement Converter {
    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        return clazz.equals(MyState.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object value, HierarchialStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        ??? - no clue here
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchialStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        ??? - no clue here
    }
}
```

Then, to create the mapper and use it:

```
XStream mapper = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
mapper.registerConverter(new MyStateEnumConverter);

SomeJson jsonObj = mapper.fromXML(jsonString);

// Should print "closed"
System.out.println(jsonObject.getObject1().getMyState().getDesc());
```

How can I implement `marshal` and `unmarshal` so thatI get the desired mapping? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by doing 2 things:

1. Adding a lookup method as well as a `toString()` override to your enum (`MyStateEnum`); and
2. Extending XStream's `AbstractSingleValueConverter` instead of implementing `Converter`

`MyStateEnum`:

```
public enum MyStateEnum {
    // Everything you had is fine

    // But now, add:
    public static MyStateEnum getMyStateByDesc(String desc) {
        for(MyStateEnum myState : MyStateEnum.values())
            if(myState.getDesc().equals(desc))
                return myState;

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getDesc();
    }
}
```

`MyStateEnumConverter`:

```
public class MyStateEnumConverter extends AbstractSingleValueConverter {
    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        return clazz.equals(MyStateEnum.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromString(String parsedText) {
        return MyStateEnum.getMyStateByDesc(parsedText);
    }
}
```

By adding `getMyStateByDesc(String)` to your enum, you now have a way to look up all the various enumerated values from the outside, by providing a `desc` string. The `MyStateEnumConverter` (which extends `AbstractSingleValueConverter`) uses your `toString()` override under the hood to associate a`MyStateEnum` instance with a text string.

So when XStream is parsing the JSON, it sees a JSON object of, say, "opened", and this new converter knows to pass "opened" into the converter's `fromString(String)` method, which in turn uses `getMyStateByDesc(String)` to lookup the appropriate enum instance.

Don't forget to register your converter with your `XStream` instance as you already showed in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EnumToStringConverter

[Documentation](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/enums/EnumToStringConverter.html)

Example

```
@XStreamConverter(EnumToStringConverter.class)
public enum MyStateEnum {
enter code here

...
```

Use xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true)

Answer (score -2):

Why are you using xstream for json support? You have a couple of other libraries specialized in json and that do it well. Also closed without quotes is not valid json.

Try for example [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/), it will work out of the box.
The values in the json stream would be "Close", "Indeterminate", etc and when deserializing it will produce the correct enum.

```
class SomeObject {
   private MyState state;
   ...
}

Genson genson = new Genson();
// json = {"state" : "Indeterminate"}
String json = genson.serialize(new SomeObject(MyState.Indeterminate));

// deserialize back
SomeObject someObject = genson.deserialize(json, SomeObject.class);

// will print unknown
System.out.println(someObject.getDesc());
```

Comment: Correct answer to the wrong question - I'm just interested in XStream here, who's `JettisonMappedXmlDriver` is perfectly suited for JSON.